# I need help to simplify this code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a code like this but the problem is that is very inefficient (2000 lines) and I don't know how to make it simple, I have this code too when the RacePosition variable is 1, 2, 19, 20. I would like if you can help me to make it simple. I thinked about be able to replace the first three letters of variables but I'm a bit begginer and I don't know to do it.

Explanation of the code: It's a tower that display standings and every XXXPosition is different, and RacePosition is my position in the race, I puted -2 because for knowing that he is 2 places in front of me

EDIT: Now i managed to make classes of the drivers but what I need is to make this code simple

```
if (App.RacePosition > 2 && App.RacePosition < 19)
    {
        if (App.VANPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.VANDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.VANTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.VANTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.RICPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.RICDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.RICTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.RICTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.VETPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.VETDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.VETTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.VETTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.RAIPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.RAIDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.RAITeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.RAITyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.GROPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.GRODriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.GROTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.GROTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.ERIPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.ERIDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.ERITeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.ERITyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.PERPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.PERDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.PERTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.PERTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.ALOPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.ALODriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.ALOTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.ALOTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.STRPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.STRDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.STRTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.STRTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.MASPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.MASDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.MASTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.MASTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.MAGPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.MAGDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.MAGTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.MAGTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.KVYPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.KVYDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.KVYTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.KVYTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.HULPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.HULDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.HULTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.HULTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.PALPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.PALDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.PALTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.PALTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.OCOPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.OCODriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.OCOTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.OCOTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.VESPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.VESDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.VESTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.VESTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.HAMPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.HAMDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.HAMTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.HAMTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.SAIPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.SAIDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.SAITeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.SAITyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.BOTPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.BOTDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.BOTTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.BOTTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        if (App.WEHPosition == App.RacePosition - 2)
        {
            TowerFirstName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.WEHDriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirst.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.WEHTeamID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            TowerFirstTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.WEHTyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what `HAMPosition` is, how it is different from `WEHPosition` and what `- 2` stands for.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: It looks like you need to refactor some of the datatypes that are outside of this tiny peephole...

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your domain gets more complex, using simple variables for everything quickly leads to awful code. Start creating classes for your domain models.

The above code could benefit from using a dictionary with the "position" as key (e.g. `App.VANPosition`) and the "driver id", "team id" and "tyre compound" as value (e.g. `App.VANDriverID`, `App.VANTeamID`, `App.VANTyreCompound`)

Comment: When I create classes I can't acess to his values (including using static propety) cause this code and the variables are in different codes, also I can't put variables on these code because there are another codes that acess to that variables

Comment: If you can put references to the values in your code, you can wrap those references into your own class object that will then allow you to simplify. It shouldn't matter that much that you don't have access to change the structure of the originating code base.